# When importing a package in R, do the imports to that package also get imported?

Tags: r, roxygen2

When creating a new package, if you `import` a package, do the imports to the imported package also get imported?

#### Example

Suppose

- package A imports packages B, C and D
- You create a new package E, which imports package A

Will your new package also contain packages B, C, and D?

#### Notes

Another way to ask this could be: can we access the functions within a package that was imported to another package which is finally loaded/imported in the current environment?

Comment: Every package has its own dependencies, packages, where has their own and go on... If you download a package you have to download all the depended packages. Using the function install.packages, if any package is missing then R will produce errors but you can set the argument dependencies to true so R can download all the depended packages recursively.

Comment: When developing a package, all packages that you rely on should be declared explicitly, in the list of imports in the `DESCRIPTION` file, and all function calls should be pre-pended by the name of their package, i.e. `package::function()`. i.e. if you use it, declare it, regardless of whether it is a dependency of another package you import.  http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html